# Compiling gRPC protobuf - "program not found or is not executable"

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I am struggling to compile my .proto files to generate the gRPC stubs in Python.

My current working directory is ./predictor. I have a simulator.proto file in the ./proto folder.

The readme for the project I am working on says I should run

```
protoc -I ../proto/ --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_python_plugin` ../proto/simulator.proto
```

This fails and gives me

```
: program not found or is not executable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I try it with `python -m grpc_tools.protoc ...` and it still doesn't work.
I have double checked that I have grpc installed, I have reinstalled it with pip, and also git clone'd the grpc folder and built from the source. I am not sure what else to do. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (easily!?) use `protoc` for Python and are best placed using the module as you describe.

The command should be similar to:

```sh
python \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path=../proto \
--python_out=. \
--grpc_python_out=. \
../proto/*.proto
```

Assuming that you have a parent directory called `proto` containing at least one `.proto` file and you run this command from `python`:

```
.
├── protos
│   └── x.proto
└── python
    ├── x_pb2_grpc.py
    └── x_pb2.py
```

What errors do you get when using the module?

Comment: I get `RuntimeWarning: 'grpc_tools.protoc' found in sys.modules after import of package 'grpc_tools', but prior to execution of 'grpc_tools.protoc'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
Missing output directives.`. I don't the warning matters, but I think missing output directives is a problem.

Comment: Running the command you sent generates the simulator_pb2.py file but it does not generate simulator_pb2_grpc.py

Comment: Actually I think I got it now. I was missing one of the cli flag options. Thanks for the help!